# How update all model to empty

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, observable

I have observable model

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        Car: { number: '', color: '' },
});
```

I would to update all field for this model.

Now I'm doing it so:

```
viewModel.set("Car.number", " ");
viewModel.set("Car.color", " ");
```

I would do it this in loop

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is create string const model (enum)

```
NAME_FIELD: {
            NUMBER : nameModel + "number", 
            COLOR: nameModel + "color" }
```